# How to push element after a certain value of an array

Tags: php, arrays, array-push

So we all know that `array_push` works like this:

```
<?php
$a=array("red","green");
array_push($a,"blue","yellow");
print_r($a);
?>
```

So the result would be:

```
Array ( [0] => red [1] => green [2] => blue [3] => yellow )
```

But now I need to know how can I append the *blue* and *yellow* after a certain value of the array.

So for example, if I determine that, push the *blue* and *yellow* after the *red* (which has the position of **0**), this result would be shown:

```
Array ( [0] => red [1] => blue [2] => yellow [3] => green)
```

So how can I push element after a certain value of an array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this with `array_push`. However, you can loop on the array, collect the values in a new array and `array_merge` the new colors when you find the color of your choice after which new colors need to be injected.

```
<?php

$a = array("red","green");

$newColors = ["blue","yellow"];

$result = [];

foreach($a as $color){
  $result[] = $color;
  if($color == 'red'){
    $result = array_merge($result, $newColors);
  }
}


print_r($result);
```

[**Online Demo**](https://onecompiler.com/php/3ygff9anb)